# How to determine nodes to reduce their length using `tikzpicture` environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

This is and addendum of a previous question: [How to insert elective subjects section within a diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479245/152550).

### What I want

I would like to **reduce the length of those nodes that only have a single column of a `matrix` environment of the Ti*k*z package but keeping the same space between nodes.** If possible, also do it automatically (it is not necessary at all, just know what the necessary commands are):

[image: What I want]

### What I have done

MWE:

All the following source code belongs to [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) in [the incredible accepted answer of the attached question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479883/152550). I only modified the nodes and things like that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in,footskip=0in,paperwidth=95cm,paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,fit,calc}
\tikzset{
text field/.style={text height=1.5ex,align=center,rounded corners},
nonfillable title field/.style={text height=2ex,text depth=0.3em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
fillable title field/.style={text height=3.14ex,text depth=0em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
pics/fillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/fillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[fillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {\hspace*{-0.34em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-electivesubject,width=4.5cm,charsize=8pt,height=.5cm,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
 manoooh/.style={column sep=-1.75cm,row sep=5mm},
 manooohE/.style={column sep=-2.25cm,row sep=5mm,anchor=south},
 electives/.style={column sep=-7.25cm,row sep=5mm},
 fit sep/.initial=4pt,  % change width of node (big rectangle shape)
 fit dist/.initial=3cm, % change node distance (big rectangle shape)
 inlay top sep/.initial=24pt,
 matrix top sep/.initial=24pt,
}  % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478723/152550

\makeatletter% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85531/121799
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   % To suppress page number
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[white,fill=orange] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,-2cm) node[midway,align=center,font=\Huge] {\bfseries Some text here\\\LARGE More text here};
\end{tikzpicture}

\ifdefined\mymatdist
%\typeout{got\space\mymatdist}
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\mymatdist{150pt}
\fi
\ifdefined\mymatbottom
%\typeout{got\space\mymatbottom}
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\mymatbottom{-150pt}
\fi
\ifdefined\myheight
\else
\def\myheight{0}
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\fi
\ifdefined\LstMatShifts
\else
\def\LstMatShifts{{0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}}
\fi
%\typeout{height:\myheight}
%\typeout{shifts(in):\LstMatShifts}

\vfill
\centering
\begin{Form}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % step 1: add the matrices, name them mat0, mat1 etc.
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=matrices] 
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat0) at (0*\mymatdist,{\LstMatShifts[0]}) {
        & \pic[local bounding box=A] (A) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}}; & \\
        & \pic (B) {nonfillable subject={Subject B}}; & \\
  };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat1) at (1*\mymatdist,{\LstMatShifts[1]}) {
        & \pic (C) {nonfillable subject={Subject C}}; & \\
        & \pic (D) {nonfillable subject={Subject D}}; & \\
        & \pic (E) {nonfillable subject={Subject E}}; & \\
        & \pic (F) {nonfillable subject={Subject F}}; & \\
        & \pic (G) {nonfillable subject={Subject G}}; & \\
        & \pic (H) {nonfillable subject={Subject H}}; & \\
        & \pic (I) {nonfillable subject={Subject I}}; & \\
        & \pic[draw=red] (J) {nonfillable subject={Subject J}}; & \\
    };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat2) at (2*\mymatdist,{\LstMatShifts[2]}) {
        & \pic[draw=red] (K) {nonfillable subject={Subject K}}; & \\
        & \pic (L) {nonfillable subject={Subject L}}; & \\
        & \pic (M) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}}; & \\
        & \pic (N) {nonfillable subject={Subject N}}; & \\
        & \pic (O) {nonfillable subject={Subject O}}; & \\
        & \pic (P) {nonfillable subject={Subject P}}; & \\
        & \pic (Q) {nonfillable subject={Subject Q}}; & \\
        & \pic (R) {nonfillable subject={Subject R}}; & \\
    };  
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat3) at (3*\mymatdist,{\LstMatShifts[3]}) {
        & \pic[draw=red] (S) {nonfillable subject={Subject S}}; & \\
        & \pic (T) {nonfillable subject={Subject T}}; & \\
        & \pic (U) {nonfillable subject={Subject U}}; & \\
        & \pic (V) {nonfillable subject={Subject V}}; & \\
        & \pic (W) {nonfillable subject={Subject W}}; & \\
        & \pic (X) {nonfillable subject={Subject X}}; & \\
        & \pic (Y) {nonfillable subject={Subject Y}}; & \\
        & \pic (Z) {nonfillable subject={Subject Z}}; & \\
    };
  \matrix[manooohE,column sep=8pt] (matE3) at (3*\mymatdist,\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L3E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; &
        \pic (L3E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat4) at (4*\mymatdist,{\LstMatShifts[4]}) {
        & \pic[draw=red] (AA) {nonfillable subject={Subject AA}}; & \\
        \pic (AB) {nonfillable subject={Subject AB}}; & & \pic (AC) {nonfillable subject={Subject AC}}; \\
        & \pic (AD) {nonfillable subject={Subject AD}}; & \\
        & \pic (AE) {nonfillable subject={Subject AE}}; & \\
        & \pic (AF) {nonfillable subject={Subject AF}}; & \\
        & \pic (AG) {nonfillable subject={Subject AG}}; & \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE4) at (4*\mymatdist,\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L4E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat5) at (5*\mymatdist,{\LstMatShifts[5]}) {
        & \pic (AH) {nonfillable subject={Subject AH}}; & \\
        & \pic (AI) {nonfillable subject={Subject AI}}; & \\
        & \pic[draw=red] (AJ) {nonfillable subject={Subject AJ}}; & \\
        & \pic (AK) {nonfillable subject={Subject AK}}; & \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE5) at (5*\mymatdist,\mymatbottom) {
        & \pic (L5E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; & \\
        & \pic (L5E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; & \\
        & \pic (L5E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; & \\
        & \pic (L5E4) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; & \\
        & \pic (L5E5) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; & \\
    };
 \end{scope}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{0}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,5} %<- if you have more or less matrices, adjust 3       
 {
  \ifnodedefined{matE\X}{% has inlay
   \path let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$),
    \p2=($(matE\X.north east)-(matE\X.south west)$)
      in 
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{max(\x1,\mywidth)}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\y2+%
       \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},%
       \myheight)}
     \xdef\mywidth{\mywidth}\xdef\myheight{\myheight}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\myshift}{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\y2)/2}
     \ifnum\X=0
     \xdef\LstMatShifts{\myshift pt}
     \else
     \xdef\LstMatShifts{\LstMatShifts,\myshift pt}
     \fi};}{% no inlay
   \path 
    let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$)  in 
  \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{max(\x1,\mywidth)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},\myheight)} 
    \xdef\mywidth{\mywidth}\xdef\myheight{\myheight}};
    \ifnum\X=0
    \xdef\LstMatShifts{0pt}
    \else
    \xdef\LstMatShifts{\LstMatShifts,0pt}
    \fi
     }
  \node[anchor=south,yshift=1cm,align=center,font=\LARGE\bfseries\boldmath] 
  at (mat\X |-matrices.north) (L\X) {Level $\X$};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   % the fit parameters determine the shape of the background rectangles
   \node[fit=(L\X) (mat\X) (matrices.south-|mat\X.south),inner ysep=5mm,
   minimum width=\mymatdist-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}/2,
   fill=orange!30,rounded corners=50pt](F\X){};
  \end{scope}}
 %\typeout{height1:\myheight} % 
 %
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydist}{\mywidth+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit
 sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}}
 \xdef\mydist{\mydist}
 \def\mymatbottom{0pt}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,5} %
 {\ifnodedefined{matE\X}{\path let \p1=($(mat\X.north)-(mat\X.south)$),
      \p2=($(matE\X.north)-(matE\X.south)$),
      \n1={max(abs(\y1)/2+abs(\y2)+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep},\mymatbottom)}
     in \pgfextra{\xdef\mymatbottom{\n1}}
     node[anchor=south east,xshift=-3cm,font=\LARGE\bfseries] (El\X)
      at (matE\X.north){Electives};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]      
    \node[fit=(matE\X) (El\X)] (FE\X){};
    \fill[blue!30,rounded corners=30pt] (\X*\mymatdist-
    \mymatdist/2+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}/4+10pt,0|-FE\X.north)
    rectangle (\X*\mymatdist+
    \mymatdist/2-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}/4-10pt,0|-FE\X.south);
  \end{scope}}{}}
 %\typeout{shifts(end):\LstMatShifts} 
 \makeatletter
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\mymatdist{\mydist pt}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\mymatbottom{-\mymatbottom}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myheight{\myheight}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\LstMatShifts{{\LstMatShifts}}\relax}
 \makeatother

 % now add the arrows 
 \foreach \X in {C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J} {
    \draw[very thick,blue,-latex] (A-Title) to[out=0,in=180] (\X-Title);
    \draw[very thick,red,-latex] (B-Title) to[out=0,in=180] (\X-Title);
 }
 \foreach \X in {L,O} {
    \draw[very thick,orange,-latex] (C-Title) to[out=0,in=180] (\X-Title);
 }
 \foreach \X in {K,N,O,Z} {
    \draw[very thick,green,-latex] (D-Title) to[out=0,in=180] (\X-Title);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{Form}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have done]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proposal with ducky (i.e. nonexistent ;-) explanations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in,footskip=0in,paperwidth=95cm,paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{behind}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{behind,background,main,foreground}
\tikzset{
text field/.style={text height=1.5ex,align=center,rounded corners},
nonfillable title field/.style={text height=2ex,text depth=0.3em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
fillable title field/.style={text height=3.14ex,text depth=0em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
pics/fillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/fillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[fillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {\hspace*{-0.34em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-electivesubject,width=4.5cm,charsize=8pt,height=.5cm,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
 manoooh/.style={column sep=-1.75cm,row sep=5mm},
 manooohE/.style={column sep=-2.25cm,row sep=5mm,anchor=south},
 electives/.style={column sep=-7.25cm,row sep=5mm},
 fit sep/.initial=4pt,  % change width of node (big rectangle shape)
 fit dist/.initial=40pt, % change node distance (big rectangle shape)
 inlay top sep/.initial=24pt,
 matrix top sep/.initial=24pt,
 manoooh curve/.style={to path={let \p1=($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$) 
 in (\tikztostart) .. controls ($(\tikztostart)+(#1*\x1,0)$)
 and ($(\tikztotarget)+(-#1*\x1,0)$) .. (\tikztotarget)}},
 manoooh curve/.default=0.3
}  % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478723/152550

\makeatletter% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85531/121799
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   % To suppress page number
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[white,fill=orange] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,-2cm) node[midway,align=center,font=\Huge] {\bfseries Some text here\\\LARGE More text here};
\end{tikzpicture}

\ifdefined\mymatbottom
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\mymatbottom{-150pt}
\fi
\ifdefined\myheight
\else
\def\myheight{0}
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\fi
\ifdefined\LstMatYShifts
\else
\def\LstMatYShifts{{0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}}
\fi
\ifdefined\LstMatXShifts
\else
\def\LstMatXShifts{{0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}}
\fi

%\typeout{height:\myheight}
%\typeout{xshifts(in):\LstMatXShifts}

\vfill
\centering
\begin{Form}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % step 1: add the matrices, name them mat0, mat1 etc.
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=matrices] 
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat0) at ({\LstMatXShifts[0]},{\LstMatYShifts[0]}) {
         \pic[local bounding box=A] (A) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}};  \\
         \pic (B) {nonfillable subject={Subject B}};  \\
  };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat1) at ({\LstMatXShifts[1]},{\LstMatYShifts[1]}) {
         \pic (C) {nonfillable subject={Subject C}};  \\
         \pic (D) {nonfillable subject={Subject D}};  \\
         \pic (E) {nonfillable subject={Subject E}};  \\
         \pic (F) {nonfillable subject={Subject F}};  \\
         \pic (G) {nonfillable subject={Subject G}};  \\
         \pic (H) {nonfillable subject={Subject H}};  \\
         \pic (I) {nonfillable subject={Subject I}};  \\
         \pic[draw=red] (J) {nonfillable subject={Subject J}};  \\
    };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat2) at ({\LstMatXShifts[2]},{\LstMatYShifts[2]}) {
         \pic[draw=red] (K) {nonfillable subject={Subject K}};  \\
         \pic (L) {nonfillable subject={Subject L}};  \\
         \pic (M) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}};  \\
         \pic (N) {nonfillable subject={Subject N}};  \\
         \pic (O) {nonfillable subject={Subject O}};  \\
         \pic (P) {nonfillable subject={Subject P}};  \\
         \pic (Q) {nonfillable subject={Subject Q}};  \\
         \pic (R) {nonfillable subject={Subject R}};  \\
    };  
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat3) at ({\LstMatXShifts[3]},{\LstMatYShifts[3]}) {
         \pic[draw=red] (S) {nonfillable subject={Subject S}};  \\
         \pic (T) {nonfillable subject={Subject T}};  \\
         \pic (U) {nonfillable subject={Subject U}};  \\
         \pic (V) {nonfillable subject={Subject V}};  \\
         \pic (W) {nonfillable subject={Subject W}};  \\
         \pic (X) {nonfillable subject={Subject X}};  \\
         \pic (Y) {nonfillable subject={Subject Y}};  \\
         \pic (Z) {nonfillable subject={Subject Z}};  \\
    };
  \matrix[manooohE] (matE3) at ({\LstMatXShifts[3]},\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L3E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; & &
        \pic (L3E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
        & \pic (L3E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  & \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat4) at ({\LstMatXShifts[4]},{\LstMatYShifts[4]}) {
        & \pic[draw=red] (AA) {nonfillable subject={Subject AA}}; & \\
        \pic (AB) {nonfillable subject={Subject AB}}; & & \pic (AC) {nonfillable subject={Subject AC}}; \\
        & \pic (AD) {nonfillable subject={Subject AD}}; & \\
        & \pic (AE) {nonfillable subject={Subject AE}}; & \\
        & \pic (AF) {nonfillable subject={Subject AF}}; & \\
        & \pic (AG) {nonfillable subject={Subject AG}}; & \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE4) at ({\LstMatXShifts[4]},\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L4E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat5) at ({\LstMatXShifts[5]},{\LstMatYShifts[5]}) {
         \pic (AH) {nonfillable subject={Subject AH}};  \\
         \pic (AI) {nonfillable subject={Subject AI}};  \\
         \pic[draw=red] (AJ) {nonfillable subject={Subject AJ}};  \\
         \pic (AK) {nonfillable subject={Subject AK}};  \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE5) at ({\LstMatXShifts[5]},\mymatbottom) {
         \pic (L5E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E4) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E5) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
    };
 \end{scope}
 \draw[-latex] (I-Title) to[manoooh curve] (AK-Title);
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastwidth}{0}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,5} %<- if you have more or less matrices, adjust 3       
 {
  \node[anchor=south,yshift=1cm,align=center,font=\LARGE\bfseries\boldmath] 
  at (mat\X |-matrices.north) (L\X) {Level $\X$}; 
  \ifnodedefined{matE\X}{% has inlay
   \node[xshift=1em,anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries,opacity=0] (matEl\X) at (matE\X.north west) {Electives};
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \path let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$) in
   node[fit=(matE\X) (matEl\X),inner ysep=5mm,fill=blue!30,rounded
   corners=40pt,minimum width=\x1-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep},
   inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}](F\X){};
   \node[xshift=1em,anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries] 
   (matEl\X) at ([xshift=1.3em]F\X.west|-matEl\X.center) {Electives};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \path let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$),
    \p2=($(F\X.north east)-(F\X.south west)$),
    \n1={max(abs(\y1)/2+abs(\y2)/2+0*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep},\mymatbottom)}
      in 
    \pgfextra{\xdef\mymatbottom{\n1}
       \ifnum\X=0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
       \else    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{\groupwidth+max(\x1,\x2)/2+\lastwidth/2+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}}
       \fi
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastwidth}{max(\x1,\x2)+8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}}
       \xdef\lastwidth{\lastwidth}
       \xdef\groupwidth{\groupwidth}     
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\y2+%
         \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},%
         \myheight)}
       \xdef\myheight{\myheight}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myshift}{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\y2)/2}
       \ifnum\X=0
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\myshift pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{0pt}
       \else
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\LstMatYShifts,\myshift pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{\LstMatXShifts,\groupwidth pt}
       \fi};    
   % the fit parameters determine the shape of the background rectangles
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{behind}
   \node[fit=(L\X) (mat\X) (matrices.south-|mat\X.south)
   (matE\X) (matEl\X),inner ysep=8mm,inner xsep=4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep},
   fill=orange!30,rounded corners=50pt](F\X){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}}{% no inlay
   \path 
    let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$),
     \n1={max(abs(\y1)/2,\mymatbottom)}
      in 
     \pgfextra{\xdef\mymatbottom{\n1}
       \ifnum\X=0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
       \else    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{\groupwidth+\x1/2+\lastwidth/2+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}}
       \fi
       \xdef\groupwidth{\groupwidth}
       \xdef\lastwidth{\x1}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},\myheight)} 
       \xdef\myheight{\myheight}
       \ifnum\X=0
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{0pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{0pt}
       \else
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\LstMatYShifts,0pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{\LstMatXShifts,\groupwidth pt}
       \fi};   
   % the fit parameters determine the shape of the background rectangles
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{behind}
   \node[fit=(L\X) (mat\X) (matrices.south-|mat\X.south),inner ysep=8mm,
   fill=orange!30,rounded corners=50pt](F\X){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   }
  }
 \makeatletter
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\mymatbottom{-\mymatbottom}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myheight{\myheight}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\LstMatYShifts{{\LstMatYShifts}}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\LstMatXShifts{{\LstMatXShifts}}\relax}
 \makeatother

 % now add the arrows 
 \foreach \X in {C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J} {
    \draw[very thick,blue,-latex] (A-Title) to[out=0,in=180] (\X-Title);
    \draw[very thick,red,-latex] (B-Title) to[out=0,in=180] (\X-Title);
 }
 \foreach \X in {L,O} {
    \draw[very thick,orange,-latex] (C-Title) to[out=0,in=180] (\X-Title);
 }
 \foreach \X in {K,N,O,Z} {
    \draw[very thick,green,-latex] (D-Title) to[out=0,in=180] (\X-Title);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{Form}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I very like your approximation! Can you explain what are some of the changes you have applied, please?

Comment: @manooooh I'll try tomorrow. (What are the appropriate dimensions for the inlays?)

Comment: Thanks for correcting it, the output is awesome! I am trying to add a new `elective subject` into the blue shape of `Level 3`. To do that I am using `& \pic (L3E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\ `, but this makes an unwanted position; this `pic` is not centered, and if we use 3 columns instead of 2 the output goes crazy. How can we center it?

Comment: I am using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21129/152550) but it gives me error. 1) I first loaded `matrix` inside `usetikzlibrary`. 2)  Went to `matE3` and added  `nodes in empty cells,matrix of nodes` inside that `matrix`. 3) Added a new line after the first row: `& \\ `. 4) After the `matrix` command I added the following code: `\node[fit=(matE3-2-1)(matE3-2-2)]{\pic (L3E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};};`. 5) Compiled it but it says "! Undefined control sequence. l.150 \node[fit=(matE3-2-1)(matE3-2-2)]{\pic (L3E2) {nonfillable elective ...". (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) I also tried deleting the `;` in the `...Subject}};...` but same problem. the Any suggestion?